# filter a datagridview using linq to entities

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, datagridview, filter, linq-to-entities

I just found linq to entities. I decided to use it in my program.

I have a database with Sql server 2014. I imported my database with the help of "Ado.net entity data model".

Until then everything is fine, I created a context and I binded it on a bindingsource and the bindingsource is binded to my datagridview.

The problem is that when I come to filter my datagridview with the help of bindingsource.filter, nothing happens.

```
 bindingsource.DataSource = entitiesCOOP.completeInventory.ToList()
dgv.DataSource = bindingsource

bindingsource.Filter = String.Format("description LIKE '" & txt_description.Text & "%'")
 dgv.Refresh()
```

Did I make a mistake somewhere? Or is it the fact that it is a list that does not allow to filter?

Otherwise, would there be another way I could use with the help of entity framework to filter a datagridview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter the incoming request. I did not include the Like operator since you had no wildcards which would be the same as equals - roughly.

```
bindingsource.DataSource = entitiesCOOP.completeInventory.
                           Where(Function(ci) ci.description = txt_description.Text).ToList
```

Comment: I have a wildcard. my mistake. Your method can work. But, how can I do for if I enter for example a "L" all the words starting with "L" come out?

Comment: I figured out. Thanks for your help. It's appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried txt_description.Text.StartsWith("L",StringComparision.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)